# ENS Reveal execution error from MyEtherWallet

Tags: myetherwallet, ens, trezor

good day!  I have experienced execution errors from revealing the ENS bids.  I've tried two different bids, and the error occurs to both bids. I use Trezor vis MEW btw.  Is there anything that I'm missing?

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

#### You need to ensure that the information you are sending is exactly the same as the bid, otherwise the connection cannot be made on the blockchain.

Please double check:

- The name you are entering is the same that you bid on.
- The bid amount is the same as your bid amount when you bid.
- The secret is the same
- You are sending from the same account.

## How to Debug

#### First, look up your address on etherscan.io in order to find the transaction in which you placed your bid.

Look for:

- An outgoing transaction (orange)
- To ENS-Registrar
- With an ETH value >= `0.01 ETH` (not one that says "0 Ether")
- Was sent 2-4 days ago (if you are just revealing your bid now)
- That, when you click on the TX hash, has `Function: newBid(bytes32 sealedBid)` - under `Input Data`

Once you find this, copy and paste the value in the `Input Data` into a text document & remove the `MethodId:` and `[0]:` so that it looks like this: `0xce92dced69faf18dd0953d9124d7917234b0efc05c78fd0d9abfc6ffb32d512680fdbb65.`

#### Now, go to https://www.myetherwallet.com/helpers.html

Scroll to the "ENS" section, depending on what you saved, enter the following:

- The address you bid from
- ENS Name you Bid On (no '.eth' at the end!), or the namehash from your long string under "Hashed ENS Name (Label Hash)"
  The amount you bid
- Your Secret, or the sha3 secret from your long string under "Your Secret (Hashed)"

When you do this, the following four fields will populate with long data. You want compare the string you copied earlier ( `0xce92dced69faf18dd0953d9124d7917234b0efc05c78fd0d9abfc6ffb32d512680fdbb65`) to the string shown under "New Bid Data". These two should match.

Copy the "Reveal Data" string and go to https://www.myetherwallet.com/#send-transaction and unlock the wallet for the address that you placed the bid on. This address should also be the same address entered on the https://www.myetherwallet.com/helpers.html.

#### Enter the following information into the fields:

- To: `0x6090a6e47849629b7245dfa1ca21d94cd15878ef`
- Amount: `0 ETH`
- Gas Limit: `200000`
- Data: From the "Reveal Data" field on https://www.myetherwallet.com/helpers.html

#### Generate and sign your transaction.

Click your TX hash after you send it. Ensure there are no errors (you may have to refresh after about a minute.)

Then, in a new tab, go to https://etherscan.io/enslookup?q=yourname.eth and type in the name you bid on. Ensure that you see a very recent transaction from your address with "Unseal Bid" next to it.

#### You should probably also save the finalize data from the Helpers page. This will allow you to easily finalize the transaction in a few days.

Comment: Tsk! tsk! too complicated to use myetherwallet. why not make it user friendly.. most users are not internet savvy.

Comment: I would strongly discourage people who are not internet savvy from using our website. Like. Please don't. 
Furthermore, if you save your information like we tell you to 4 separate times during the bidding process, and then enter that information in during the reveal, there will be no errors.